# how to update an array in object using useState

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create function which adds and removes an item to/from todo in below array, receiving the item from an input form.
I thought I could use spread like below and use it within setDays but an error occurs, which says 'todo is not defined'.

```
 const [days, setDays] = useState([
   { day: 'mon', id: 'mon', todo: ['do something'] },
   { day: 'tue', id: 'tue', todo: [] },
   { day: 'wed', id: 'wed', todo: [] },
   { day: 'thu', id: 'thu', todo: [] },
   { day: 'fri', id: 'fri', todo: [] },
   { day: 'sat', id: 'sat', todo: [] },
   { day: 'sun', id: 'sun', todo: [] },
 ]);

 const handleAdd = (day, item) => {
   const newday = { ...day, todo: [...todo, item] };
 };
```

Comment: setDays(days.map((v)=> {return v.id === day?{...v, todo:[...v.todo, item]} : v;}))

Comment: "todo is undefined" because you're referencing `...todo` but have not extracted it from the state. Also, your state is a complex object, consider using [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) which is better suited for such use-cases compared to `useState` which is more suitable for simple/primitive data.